# $H^2$ norm of the Resolvent of the Laplacian on the upper half plane

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Delta$ denote the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}$. For $\operatorname{Im}{\lambda} > 0$ it is given by the spectral theorem that for the resolvent
$$R_0(\lambda) := (-\Delta - \lambda^2)^{-1}$$
we have the bound
$$||R_0(\lambda)||_{L^2 \to L^2} \leq \frac{1}{|\lambda| \operatorname{Im}\lambda} \quad \operatorname{Im}\lambda > 0$$
Why is it then the case that 
$$||R_0(\lambda)||_{L^2 \to H^2} \leq C\frac{1 + |\lambda|^2}{|\lambda| \operatorname{Im}\lambda} \quad \operatorname{Im} \lambda > 0$$

I know that from the definition we have

\begin{align}
||R_0(\lambda)||_{L^2 \to H^2} &\leq C \big(||\Delta R_0(\lambda)||_{L^2 \to L^2} + ||R_0(\lambda)||_{L^2 \to L^2}\big)\\
&\leq C\big(||Id||_{L^2 \to L^2} + (|\lambda|^2+1)||R_0(\lambda)||_{L^2 \to L^2} \big)
\end{align}

Where the second line followed from the resolvent being an inverse for $\Delta - \lambda^2$. However, I'm not sure how to absorb the norm from the identity into the
$$(1+ |\lambda|^2)||R_0(\lambda)||_{L^2 \to L^2}$$

Comment: The resolvent should be $(-\Delta-\lambda I)^{-1}$. Why do you have a square on $\lambda$?

Comment: This is in the context of scattering theory where after taking a Fourier Transform of the wave equation our operators look like $-\Delta + V - \lambda^2$ with $V$ a potential function. So the inverses studied look like $(-\Delta + V - \lambda^2)^{-1}$

Comment: Then you should not call that the resolvent, because the resolvent has a very specific meaning.

Comment: Ah, ok the text calls it the free resolvent. I'll change that!